# Shuffle elements from three vectors using AVX

Tags: intrinsics, avx, avx2

After doing few operations I got following three intermediate vectors.

```
__m256 Vec1 = [a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7];    //8 float values
__m256 Vec2 = [b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7];    //8 float values
__m256 Vec3 = [c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7];    //8 float values
```

I should rearrange these vectors as shown below for further processing.

```
__m256 ReVec1 = [a0 a1 b0 b1 c0 c1 a2 a3];
__m256 ReVec2 = [b2 b3 c2 c3 a4 a5 b4 b5];
__m256 ReVec3 = [c4 c5 a6 a7 b6 b7 c6 c7];
```

How can I shuffle three Vectors in AVX?

Comment: Which CPUs do you care about this being efficient on?  Just Intel and/or Zen 2, or do you also care about Zen1 where lane-crossing shuffles are quite slow?  (Not sure yet if there are multiple good options to pick from that would give different tradeoffs.)

Comment: Looks like elements always stay in pairs, so you can probably use `vshufpd` as a building block which is a 2-input in-lane shuffle of 64-bit chunks, allowing a different immediate control for the high and low lanes.  (But with restrictions on what can come from where).  Or possibly even `vpalignr` to do in-lane shifting in of bytes?  Immediate blends are efficient; if you can blend the new elements in to vectors, then you can put things in the right order with `vpermpd` (lane crossing)

Comment: Ok, so the final position of `b`'s elements could be achieved by an in-lane shuffle to swap 64-bit halves of each 128-bit lane, ready to blend into each of the 3 outputs.  `a` and `c`'s elements could get where they're needed with one `vpermpd` lane-crossing shuffle each.  Doing better than 3 shuffles + 6 blends would require finding ways to use 2-input shuffles, I think.

Comment: If you pretend that `a0a1`, `a2a3` is one element each, this is like a 3x4 transpose. For 3x8 transpose, Intel published an article once, which probably is adaptable to 3x4: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/3d-vector-normalization-using-256-bit-intel-advanced-vector-extensions-intel-avx.html. You may be more efficient if either the input or the output is actually from/to memory (no need for lane-crossing shuffles)

Comment: I found a solution with 6 blends and 2 shuffles (only 1 cross-lane shuffle). The trick is to first blend the `a` and `c` elements together which needs to be shuffled between lanes (to get `[c4c5 a6a7 c0c1 a2a3]`). And it is possible to replace 2 blends + 1 shuffle by two 2-input shuffles (`[a0a1 b0b1 a4a5 b4b5]` and `[b2b3 c2c3 b6b7 c6c7]`). The rest is just 3 blends.